# save selected value in database as id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two tables as shown, when employee edits its details department_id save as 0 in database

```
employee                       department
id| name|department_id     id|department_name
1 |abc  |1                  1|HR    
2 |xyz  |4                  2|Finance   
3 |asd  |3                  3|Developer
```

and this view part

```
<tr>
    <th> Department </th>
    <td> 
        <SELECT name="department_id" style="width:180px;" >
            <?php 
            foreach($departments as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php $employee['department_id'] ;?>"
            <?php  if ($row['id']== $stakehholder['department_id'])
            {
            echo 'selected';
            }
            ?>>
            <?php echo $row['department_name'];?>
            </option> 
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </SELECT>
    </td>
    <td> <?php echo form_error('department_id'); ?> </td>
</tr>
```

after edit 0 value get store in database

Comment: may be $row['department_id'] == $stakehholder['department_id']

Comment: is it correct your comparison between a "department_name" to a "department_id"?

Comment: @DamienPirsy its mistake from my side its 'id' not department_name

Comment: You stole my avatar :(

Comment: @Codeeek i didnt stole..see my profile...member for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forget **echo** `<option value="<?php $employee['department_id']; ?>"`

```
<SELECT name="department_id" style="width:180px;" >
    <?php foreach($departments as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['department_id']; ?>"
            <?php if ($row['department_name']== $stakehholder['department_id']) {
                echo 'selected';
            }
           ?>>
        <?php echo $row['department_name']; ?>
        </option> 
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </SELECT>
```

Comment: Alex if u dont know PHP then dont comment and down vote

Comment: @hunter still its store as 0 in db

Comment: put the result of print_r($departments) please here

Comment: @RanaSoyab now i m not able to save new selected value

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $row['department_id']; ?> write this before it was <option value="<?php echo $employee['department_id']; ?>"

Comment: @SoftwareDev THANKS for accepting the answer :) many people use answer but didn't accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

updated line is in as below

```
<option value="<?php echo $employee['department_id'] ;?>






<tr>
    <th> Department </th>
    <td> 
        <SELECT name="department_id" style="width:180px;" >
            <?php 
            foreach($departments as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $employee['department_id'] ;?>"
            <?php  if ($row['department_name']== $stakehholder['department_id'])
            {
            echo 'selected';
            }
            ?>>
            <?php echo $row['department_name'];?>
            </option> 
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </SELECT>
    </td>
    <td> <?php echo form_error('department_id'); ?> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @SoftwareDev okay can you pls check using chrome inpect element.

Answer (score 1):

you have forgot to echo department_id in option value attribute and second you are comparing name to id which never match if id is int and name not.

try this updated code:

```
<SELECT name="department_id" style="width:180px;" >
     <?php 
     foreach($departments as $row): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['department_id'] ;?>"
     <?php  if ($row['department_id']== $stakehholder['department_id'])
     {
        echo 'selected';
     }
    ?>>
    <?php echo $row['department_name'];?>
    </option> 
    <?php endforeach ?>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: ok, what browser you are using. check what is the value in option and let me know.

Comment: i m using chrome   and this is what i get         <option value> HR </option>
<option value  selected> Finance </option>
<option value> Developer</option>

Comment: ok, it means department id not printing. comment your above code and then echo your department id simply and check what is print on page like this <?php echo "<pre>"; var_dump($departments); echo "</pre>"; ?>. Check what structure printed on page.